# Why is "Extract template" not showing on a TeamCity 11 build configuration?

Tags: teamcity

I have laboriously built up a build configuration and I want to extract its steps to a template. The Actions menu looks like this. `Extract template` should be there, right above `Extract meta-runner`, according to what I've read in the TeamCity docs but it is not there. Why might this happen?

[image: Actions menu without Extract Template]

EDIT: It is not a permissions issue. I am an administrator of this instance. Furthermore I can manually create a template and manually add new build steps. I'd like to extract instead, because it's so much easier, but I can't.